# Ways to improve the speed / efficiency of my jquery / ajax / php call?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a table with 80 articles in it, I have a checkbox for each article.
I have code (AJAX, PHP) to activate / deactivate the articles in bulk while checkboxes are checked.
I am finding my ajax call takes 2+ seconds to activate / deactivate all 80 records, this seems slow, can you see a way to improve my code?

All help appreciated!

**Here is my Jquery / Ajax:**

```
$(document).on("click",".applybtn",function() {
    // GET SELECTOR
    var selector = $("#selector").attr("name");
    // GET OPTIONS
    var option = $("#control").val();
    var option2 = $("#control2").val();

    if($(".idcheck").is(":checked")) {
        // GET CHECKBOXS
        var val = [];
        $(".idcheck:checked").each(function(i) {
            val[i] = $(this).val();
        });
        if(selector === 'article' || selector === 'articlecats') {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "controllers/articlecontrol.php",
                data: { id: val, option: option, option2: option2, selector: selector },
                success: function(data){
                    if(option == 'delete' || option2 == 'delete') {
                        $(".idcheck:checked").each(function() {
                            $(this).closest("tr").remove();
                        })
                            }
                    if(option == 'activate' || option2 == 'activate' || option == 'deactivate' || option2 == 'deactivate') {
                        document.location.reload(true);
                    }
                    $('.successmessage').html(data).fadeIn("fast").fadeOut(3000);
                    if($('.select-all').is(':checked')) {
                        $('.select-all').prop('checked', false);
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        $('.errormessage').html("<div class='error'>Please Make Your Selection<\/div>").fadeIn("fast").fadeOut(3000);
    }
});
```

**Here is my PHP:**

```
if (isset($_POST['option']) || isset($_POST['option2'])) {

    // MULTI ACTIVATE ARTICLE
    if ($selector === 'article' && $option === 'activate' || $option2 === 'activate') {
        $id = $id;
        foreach($id as $val) {
            $update = array('article_active' => '1');
            $where = array('article_id' => $val);
            $sql = $database->update('wcx_articles', $update, $where);
        }
        if ($sql) { 
            echo '<div class="success">Article(s) Activated Successfully</div>';
        }
        else {
            echo '<div class="error">There was a problem Activating the Article(s) with ID'.$id.'</div>';   
        }
    }

    // MULTI DEACTIVATE ARTICLE
    if ($selector === 'article' && $option === 'deactivate' || $option2 === 'deactivate') {
        $id = $id;
        foreach($id as $val) {
            $update = array('article_active' => '0');
            $where = array('article_id' => $val);
            $sql = $database->update('wcx_articles', $update, $where);
        }
        if ($sql) { 
            echo '<div class="success">Article(s) Deactivated Successfully</div>';
        }
        else {
            echo '<div class="error">There was a problem Deactivating the Article(s) with ID'.$id.'</div>'; 
        }
    }
}
```

**I'm using a custom mysqli wrapper to make the calls to DB:**

```
// UPDATE TABLE
public function update( $table, $variables = array(), $where = array(), $limit = '' ) {

    $sql = "UPDATE ". $table ." SET ";
    foreach( $variables as $field => $value ) {

        $updates[] = "`$field` = '$value'";
    }
    $sql .= implode(', ', $updates);

    foreach( $where as $field => $value ) {
        $value = $value;

        $clause[] = "$field = '$value'";
    }
    $sql .= ' WHERE '. implode(' AND ', $clause);

    if( !empty( $limit ) ) {
        $sql .= ' LIMIT '. $limit;
    }

    $query = mysqli_query( $this->link, $sql );

    if( mysqli_error( $this->link ) ) {
        $this->log_db_errors( mysqli_error( $this->link ), $sql, 'Fatal' );
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: it's ajax, which means you're doing an http request, which means you're doing a full-blown tcp connection. You can optimize and tune and polish this code until it executes in 0-time, but you're still going to be stuck with the fact that you're going to send it over a network and can do nothing to speed that up.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about improving already working code, and may be better suited for [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Sorry, its my first time here, thanks for your advice ill take a look at code review!

Comment: Try recoding the PHP so that you update all rows at once, rather than performing a separate `UPDATE` query for each ID. Use a query with `WHERE article_id IN (<list of IDs>)`.

Comment: What exactly takes 2 seconds? https://www.igvita.com/posa/high-performance-networking-in-google-chrome/#resource-request

Comment: Where does the 2 seconds actually occur? I don't see any timing information in your question. I.e. how long does the request take to send / receive (how long are you waiting for the response). In your PHP you can set a variable to `microtime(true)` at the beginning of your script and then subtract the time at the end of the script to determine how much of this latency is caused by the PHP execution. Once you know where the bottleneck is, you can attempt to remedy the situation without taking stabs in the dark. ALSO, it looks like you're using non-sanitized input in your query, don't do that...

Comment: Rather than multiple individal sql queries, do ONE: `WHERE id IN(1,3,9)`

Comment: Executing 80 sequential updates can be time consuming.  As the others have commented, try to do this in a single update statement.

Comment: @Barmar that sounds like a great idea, i will try that asap!

Comment: Im using firebugs console to check the time of the ajax POST it takes 2+ seconds, i will try what you have suggested, thanks so much for all your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're performing a single SQL update query for each article you're updating.  Consider changing your PHP script so that you perform a single update for multiple articles.

Instead of generating SQL like this:

`UPDATE wcx_articles SET article_active = 1 WHERE article_id = 123;`

`UPDATE wcx_articles SET article_active = 1 WHERE article_id = 456;`

`UPDATE wcx_articles SET article_active = 1 WHERE article_id = 789;`

Performing one single update would likely be more efficient:

`UPDATE wcx_articles SET article_active = 1 WHERE article_id IN (123, 456, 789);`

That would be a decent starting point for improving efficiency of your code.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

**PHP**

```
// MULTI ACTIVATE ARTICLE
if ($selector === 'article' && $option === 'activate' || $option2 === 'activate') {
    $id = $id;
    $update = "1";
    $where = implode(',',$id);
    $sql = $database->articleADUpdate('wcx_articles', $update, $where);
if ($sql) { 
    echo '<div class="success">Article(s) Activated Successfully</div>';
}
else {
    echo '<div class="error">There was a problem Activating the Article(s) with ID'.$id.'</div>';   
}
}

public function articleADUpdate($table, $variables, $where) {
    $sql = "UPDATE wcx_articles SET article_active =".$variables." WHERE article_id IN ($where)";

    if( !empty( $limit ) ) {
        $sql .= ' LIMIT '. $limit;
    }

    $query = mysqli_query( $this->link, $sql );

    if( mysqli_error( $this->link ) ) {
        $this->log_db_errors( mysqli_error( $this->link ), $sql, 'Fatal' );
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }

}
```